# Status Code: Forbidden; Reason: The request is not authorized for this user or application

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I am trying to subscribe to Microsoft Teams Presence API for a particular user.

Request Url:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/subscriptions
```

Request Body

```json
{ 
  'changeType': 'created,updated', 
  'notificationUrl': 'https://<domain-name>/presence-notify/', 
  'resource': '/communications/presences/{id}',
  'expirationDateTime': '2020-09-10T07:37:13Z', 
  'clientState': 'secretClientState' 
}
```

Response

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ExtensionError",
    "message": "Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: Forbidden; Reason: The request is not authorized for this user or application.]",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-09-09T11:27:27",
      "request-id": "c563f94d-3c10-4c09-be35-0d1993d9a112"
    }
  }
}
```

The following delegated permissions were requested and granted by admin:

- `Presence.Read`
- `Presence.Read.All`

**Client Certificate Pic**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i am able to solve the issue. As the error mentioned `The request is not authorized for this user or application`. So i thought there might be an issue with **Access Token**. Actually i was calling API on behalf of App i.e token with grant_type as `client_credentials`. Rather i should have called API on behalf of User i.e token with grant_type as `password` as it is clearly mentioned in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/cloudcommunications-getpresencesbyuserid?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) that
permissions are delegated. I didn't use any `encryptionCertificate` still subscription was successful.

Comment: I 'm on the same situation, but I have an access token stored only:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/auth-concepts

How do I get this user token?

Comment: This is my payload string ```payload = f'grant_type=password&client_id={client_id}&client_secret={client_secret}&scope={api_scope}&userName={username}&password={password}'``` . In order to get user token , grant_type should be ```password```. ```username``` and ```password``` are the credentials of user present in tenant on behalf of which you are calling API. Please don't get confused by ```f```. Actually it's python ```f-string``` functionality.

Comment: I am calling POST request to microsoft to fetch user token. If you want complete function please post a new question.I will answer it :)

Comment: This is useful to check your token to see if it is delegated or not https://blogs.aaddevsup.xyz/2019/07/understanding-the-difference-between-application-and-delegated-permissions-from-oauth2-authentication-flows-perspective/

Comment: Can you please help me understand... Is "password" user's password for logging in to MS Teams, or is this a String constant "password"?
Also, is it required to get end user's consent for this feature, or can admin grant permission for an application?
What I need is to have access to the API by using only admin consent.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the `encryptionCertificate`. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#presence):

> **presence** subscriptions require [encryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks-with-resource-data). Subscription creation will fail if [encryptionCertificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/subscription?view=graph-rest-beta) is not specified.

Comment: Sir are you talking about the value highlighted in yellow? Question details updated.

Comment: That is an App Id. This cert is a base64-encoded representation of a certificate with a public key used to encrypt resource data in change notifications. For notifications like this, you need to provide a cert to use for encrypting the data.

Comment: I finally resolved this issue. I was using AppAccessToken as Authorization Bearer token but when i glanced over the document again, permissions mentioned are delegated permissions. So calling with UserAccessToken solved the issue.

Comment: @AmandeepSingh As per the documentation we need to have the `UserAccessToken` OR we call it `Delegated` permission, then only we can create the presence subscription. But question is we need to go through the user login flow and allow user to login to get the user token. But as per your previous comment you said you used username and password to get the token. Can you please point to MS documentation which provides more details on the API which is used for getting token based on username and password? Thanks.

Comment: @User7723337 You need to hit `POST` request on this url `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token`. Payload of the request should be `grant_type=password&client_id={client_id}&client_secret={client_secret}&scope={api_scope}&userName={username}&password={password}`. In order to get user token , grant_type should be password. username and password are the credentials of user present in tenant on behalf of which you are calling API.

Comment: Thanks for the details Amandeep, I got the link for the documentation describing the details https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc